# Calling Controller method within view Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, controller

I have a controller in Ember like so:

```
App.TasksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    search: function(term){ ... }
})
```

And I have the relative view, with a custom text field, as such:

```
App.TasksView = Ember.View.extend({
    searchField: Ember.TextField.extend({
        keyUp: function(){ this.get('controller').search() }
    })
})
```

I however get an error saying that there is no such method.

I was wondering:

1. How can I correctly call the method defined in the controller from the view?
2. How can I debug which is the currently active controller? If I `console.log(this.get('controller'))` I get an object, but it is very confusing to navigate and to understand exactly which controller is that.

Answer (score 1):

the scope of this on the text field isn't the same scope as the tasksview, so it doesn't have access to the controller.

Honestly a better way to handle this is to bind the textfield value to something and add an observer to it.  When it changes fire off a search (or probably better would be to debounce it so you aren't firing off requests every single character they type)

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/IRAXinoP/3/edit

Comment: Thank you, this gets me going further. What would the answer to the second question, be? How do I correctly debug what's going on? Console.logging returns objects that are very confusing, how do I disambiguate among them?

Comment: Ember inspector works really well, additionally looking at the constructor often helps for figuring out what type of object you are looking at, the proto helps too.

Comment: I ended up implementing what I wanted, but the question stands: in this situation, is there any way I can access the controller? Can I pass the context around, or something like that?